# Capistrano deploy namespace

Tags: ruby, capistrano

All capistrano documentation seems to suggest that there is a default namespace "deploy" with some standard tasks like setup, update_code, restart etc. But when I do cap -T it only shows the tasks that I have defined and not the deploy tasks. Do I need to do anything else to enable the deploy tasks. I am using capistrano version 2.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have a file named `Capfile` in a project root directory?
mine follows

```
load 'deploy' if respond_to?(:namespace) # cap2 differentiator
Dir['vendor/plugins/*/recipes/*.rb'].each { |plugin| load(plugin) }
load 'config/deploy'
```

Comment: I did not use capify to generate the Capfile hence it did not have the lines that you mention. On adding these lines it works.

Answer (score 2):

mbp:cms bladeyu [master] $ cap -T

```
cap bundle:install           # Install the current Bundler environment.
cap deploy                   # Deploys your project.
cap deploy:assets:clean      # Run the asset clean rake task.
cap deploy:assets:precompile # Run the asset precompilation rake task.
cap deploy:check             # Test deployment dependencies.
cap deploy:cleanup           # Clean up old releases.
cap deploy:cold              # Deploys and starts a `cold' application.
cap deploy:migrate           # Run the migrate rake task.
cap deploy:migrations        # Deploy and run pending migrations.
cap deploy:pending           # Displays the commits since your last deploy.
cap deploy:pending:diff      # Displays the `diff' since your last deploy.
cap deploy:rollback          # Rolls back to a previous version and restarts.
cap deploy:rollback:code     # Rolls back to the previously deployed version.
cap deploy:setup             # Prepares one or more servers for deployment.
cap deploy:symlink           # Updates the symlink to the most recently deplo...
cap deploy:update            # Copies your project and updates the symlink.
cap deploy:update_code       # Copies your project to the remote servers.
cap deploy:upload            # Copy files to the currently deployed version.
cap deploy:web:disable       # Present a maintenance page to visitors.
cap deploy:web:enable        # Makes the application web-accessible again.
cap invoke                   # Invoke a single command on the remote servers.
cap shell                    # Begin an interactive Capistrano session.
cap whenever:clear_crontab   # Clear application's crontab entries using When...
cap whenever:update_crontab  # Update application's crontab entries using Whe...


Some tasks were not listed, either because they have no description,
or because they are only used internally by other tasks. To see all
tasks, type `cap -vT'.

Extended help may be available for these tasks.
Type `cap -e taskname' to view it.
```

mbp:cms bladeyu [master] $ gem list capistrano

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

capistrano (2.9.0)
```

mbp:cms bladeyu [master] $ cap -vT

```
cap assets:cleanup           # 
cap assets:precompile        # 
cap assets:redigest          # 
cap bundle:install           # Install the current Bundler environment.
cap custom_symlink           # 
cap deploy                   # Deploys your project.
cap deploy:assets:clean      # Run the asset clean rake task.
cap deploy:assets:precompile # Run the asset precompilation rake task.
cap deploy:assets:symlink    # [internal] This task will set up a symlink to ...
cap deploy:check             # Test deployment dependencies.
cap deploy:cleanup           # Clean up old releases.
cap deploy:cold              # Deploys and starts a `cold' application.
cap deploy:finalize_update   # [internal] Touches up the released code.
cap deploy:migrate           # Run the migrate rake task.
cap deploy:migrations        # Deploy and run pending migrations.
cap deploy:pending           # Displays the commits since your last deploy.
cap deploy:pending:diff      # Displays the `diff' since your last deploy.
cap deploy:restart           # 
cap deploy:rollback          # Rolls back to a previous version and restarts.
cap deploy:rollback:cleanup  # [internal] Removes the most recently deployed ...
cap deploy:rollback:code     # Rolls back to the previously deployed version.
cap deploy:rollback:revision # [internal] Points the current symlink at the p...
cap deploy:setup             # Prepares one or more servers for deployment.
cap deploy:start             # 
cap deploy:stop              # 
cap deploy:symlink           # Updates the symlink to the most recently deplo...
cap deploy:update            # Copies your project and updates the symlink.
cap deploy:update_code       # Copies your project to the remote servers.
cap deploy:upload            # Copy files to the currently deployed version.
cap deploy:web:disable       # Present a maintenance page to visitors.
cap deploy:web:enable        # Makes the application web-accessible again.
cap invoke                   # Invoke a single command on the remote servers.
cap precompile_trace         # 
cap setup_file_tree          # 
cap shell                    # Begin an interactive Capistrano session.
cap whenever:clear_crontab   # Clear application's crontab entries using When...
cap whenever:update_crontab  # Update application's crontab entries using Whe...

Extended help may be available for these tasks.
Type `cap -e taskname' to view it.
```